# Chromium, why is zipped download so much smaller than cloning?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, tar, chromium

I'm downloading what I believe to be the exact repository of chromium yesterday in a tar version from here:

https://gsdview.appspot.com/chromium-browser-official/?marker=chromium-55.0.2883.53-testdata.tar.xz.hashe%40

However, when I uncompress it, it is only half the size (3.5gb) of the actual chromium clone (7gb).

I'm wondering why this is? Is there any way to get a compressed latest version of chromium repository? It just takes ages to download a full 7gb...

Comment: This is really frustrating, chromium is supposed to be 7gb, but I'm downloading it now and it's at 13gb already and still not finished. Does anyone have any idea of the final size of the current chromium source?